# Accessing bootstrap functionality in Jest testing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

So I'm testing my React components using Jest & Enzyme, and when I test a component that opens a bootstrap modal, I get the following error:

`TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`

makes sense, I haven't references bootstrap at any point yet, so I go ahead and add the following to my jest object in my package.json:

```
"setupFiles": [
  "./app/common/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
  "./app/common/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "./__mocks__/beforeTest.js"
 ]
```

which then gives me this error:

`Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.`

I've set `window.$` and `global.$` to jQuery to see if that would help my issue, but it doesn't seem to help either, neither does importing the bootstrap module inside my `beforeTest.js` file.

I don't need to test the functionality of the modal, I just need the error to go away. So I'm hoping to find a way to load bootstrap such that I can run `$(...).modal`. Will bootstrap even work in this environment?

Comment: Have you tried doing `require('../app/common/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js');require('../app/common/js/bootstrap.min.js')` in your `beforeTest`?

Comment: @SimenB Yes, that also gives me the `Bootstrap's Javascript requires jQuery.` error. FWIW, I'm able to spoof the functionality by creating a fake jquery function.

Comment: Was this issue ever solved? Having the same problem right now.

Comment: @Siavash I never got a good solution for adding actual jQuery. I ended up stubbing out a fake version with `modal` and other functions I needed in order to get the tests to pass.

Comment: Coming back to this a few years later -- I'll say that I never found an issue to the exact problem I was having, but I stopped working on the project so I don't know if the following answer is correct. I won't mark it as answered since I can't verify, but it seems some people are having success with it.

I imagine my issue likely had some additional scoping issues that I wasn't taking into account at the time.

Answer (score 8):

This is what helped me:

```
$.fn.modal = jest.fn();
```

The mocking will also avoids one to include Bootstrap for test suite.

Comment: that's what I was looking for!